# logic to create two dimensional array into multi dimensional object using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

logic to create two dimensional array into multi dimensional object using javascript

i am stuck in a situation where i have two dimensional array, and i have to create a multidimensiaonl array based on that

example :

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4,5], [6,7].......n]
```

and i need a object like

```
{"1":{"3":{6:{...},7:{...}},"4":{6:{...},7:{...}},"5":{6:{...},7:{...}}},"2":{"3":{6:{...},7:{...}},"4":{6:{...},7:{...}},"5":{6:{...},7:{...}}}}
```

let say

```
arr = [[1,2],[3,4]]
```

then {1:{3,4}, 2:{3,4}}

```
if arr = [[1,2],[3,4,5], [6,7]]
```

then 
    result  = {"1":{"3":{6,7},"4":{6,7},"5":{6,7}},"2":{"3":{6,7},"4":{6,7},"5":{6,7}}}

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You need to recursively dig deep.

Comment: your indicated desired result is not valid JS (`{3,4}`)... if it were hard-coded, it could be ES6 (maybe? on expandos?), but as the result of an operation, you can't get (afaik) that representation from even ES6.

Comment: what if you get  input like this  [[1,2],[3,4,5][6,7,8,9]]

Comment: @dandavis, thanks!  it is just for showing the expected, but want to clear logic behind that

Comment: @raghavendra, recursive attach all element with it's upper parent.

Comment: @raghavendra thanks, i just need some logic, not exact code,

Comment: please let me know what i missed, why it is having down vote?

Comment: {6,7} is not a valid object

Comment: as per your you the ending level object is always a invalid object

Comment: @raghavendra, i have answered my own question, actually i was looking for that piece of code.

Comment: great man keep it up. better you can add fiddle to it.

Comment: how much effort it taken?

Comment: @raghavendra thanks!, it's not about effort, i was just missing the recursive process, thanks for shomz for remind this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am answering my self for above question, for if some one needed,

```
function writeHtml(main, addthis) {
var arr = {};
if ($.isEmptyObject(main)) {
    ar = addthis;

} else {
    $.each(addthis, function(i, d) {
        ar[d] = main;

    });
}
return arr;
}


maxlen = uiarr.length - 1;
arr = {};

function callarr(i) {
if (i >= 0) {
    arr = writeHtml(arr, uiarr[i]);
    callarr(i - 1);
}

}

callarr(maxlen);
```

**where**

```
 uiarr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7],
  [8, 9, 10, 11]
 ];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = [[1, 2], [ 3, 4]];
var obj = {};

function createMultiObject(arr) {
    'use strict';
    var i = 0;
    for (i; i < arr[0].length; i = i + 1) {
        obj[arr[0][i].toString()] = arr[1];
    }
}

createMultiObject(arr);

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: thanks @OddDev, but it is limited to 2 array, i might have n element in inputt array

Comment: @devloperCK you explicity stated "two dimensional" array.

Comment: but having n number of elements